# Is it possible to adapt the sci-kit CountVectorizer for other features (not just n-grams)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, feature-extraction

I'm new to scikit and working with text data in general, and I've been using the sci-kit CountVectorizer as a start to get used to basic features of text data (n-grams) but I want to extend this to analyze for other features.

I would prefer to adapt the countvectorizer rather than make my own, because then I wouldn't have to reimplement sci-kits tf-idf transformer and classifier.

EDIT:

I'm actually still thinking about specific features to be honest, but for my project I wanted to do style classification between documents. I know that for text classification, lemmatizing and stemming is popular for feature extraction, so that may be one. Other features that I am thinking of analyzing include

- Length of sentences per document within each style
- Distinct words per style. A more formal style may have a more eloquent and varied vocabulary

  - An offshoot of the previous point, but counts of adjectives in particular
- Lengths of particular words, again, slang might use much shorter phrases than a formal style
- Punctuation, especially marked pauses between statements, lengths of statements

These are a few ideas I was thinking of, but I'm thinking of more features to test!

Comment: What kind of feature extraction do you want to do?

Comment: @AndreasMueller I added some details!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extend extend the class (you can see the [source of it here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L496)) and implement what you need. However, it depends on what you want to do, which is not very clear in your question.

Comment: hmm I think yeah, my question is loaded, I need to give this some more thought, on the types of specific features. I might need to change the tokenizer too depending on what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to implement the features you listed in terms of a scikit-learn compatible transformer? Then maybe have a look at the [developer docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects) in particular  [rolling your own estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html#rolling-your-own-estimator).

You can just inherit from BaseEstimator and implement a `fit` and a `transform`. That is only necessary if you want to use pipelining, though. For using sklearn classifiers and the tfidf-transformer, it is only necessary that your feature extraction creates numpy arrays or scipy sparse matrices.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do! I'll look into those thank you, I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel, so I'll be so happy if I can just use these to implement my own features.